# results in output Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am looking for a solution to extract results (variables or parameters or else) from a job kettle.
Exactly I want to get logs about insert/update steps (if fields in database are inserted or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an error step on the Insert/Update step, if errors occur, row will be send to the error handling step, save them in an excel file and email it to your self. when a row is passed, error# and error MSG is passed as well to the error handling step.

You can pass data/rows to next transformation in job, double click the transformation and under advanced tab check "copy previous result to parameters" then in the transformation under JOB header, select get rows from results. rest is pretty much self explanatory :)

Comment: there is an error step i can't found it ??(i m working with the CE edition kettle)

Comment: Join insert step with a dummy step and then right click on insert step and choose error handling. Select dummy step from there. When any error arrives these buggy rows will be copied to dummy step. And transformation will not break.

Comment: thank you, now i can retrieve the error, code, description, but what i really want is to get the situation of the insertion because I extract data(many rows) from a web service (http post + parse), and I  try to insert in table mysql(table output step or insert/update step) so i want to know if all rows inserted or no.

Comment: @B.Mostafa, when error code and description is reached in the error step, it also has buggy rows with it, you can email the excel file, or you can count the error rows and send an email to yourself that COUNTED rows not got saved in the database...

Comment: Exactly I want to log informations about how much rows inserted, that my point, and set the log as output of my transformation.

Comment: brother, its simple, am mentioning again, count the rows using group by step against the dummy step for errors, you will get the row count with errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my time.

Comment: its clear, now i have a little different issue but this time i want to get many elements from xml response, that is repeated, see the question here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597782/get-data-from-xml-response-http-post-in-pentaho-kettle

Comment: I am there, are you online or not?